# tikz array lookup

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

Here's a very simple example; how do I replace `foo` with an array lookup as a function of `\k`? I want the red label to be `foo`, the green label to be `bar`, the blue label to be `baz`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \foreach\color [count=\k] in {red!90!black, green!50!black, blue!90!black}
  {
   \node[color=\color] at ($(0,\k)$){foo};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See “array operator” in the TikZ/PGF manual, page 927

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myarray}{{"foo","bar","baz"}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \foreach\Color [count=\k] in {red!90!black, green!50!black, blue!90!black}
  {
   \node[color=\Color] at ($(0,\k)$){\pgfmathparse{\myarray[\k-1]}\pgfmathresult};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Arrays are indexed starting from 0

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to `array` could be using two variables in `foreach`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \foreach \color/\t [count=\k] in {red!90!black/foo, 
            green!50!black/bar, blue!90!black/baz}
  {
   \node[color=\color] at ($(0,\k)$){\t};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you escape a slash, if you need a text string containing a slash?

Comment: @JasonS Insert text with slash inside a pair of braces: `{.../...}`